# Azure Data Factory development with multiple users without using Source Control

Tags: azure-data-factory

While working on a single Azure Data Factory solution with no Source Control. Is it possible to work parallelly for a team of 3 or more developers, without corrupting the main JSON?
Scenario: 
All developers are accessing the same ADF and working on different pipelines at the same time. One of the developer publishes his/her updates, does it somehow overwrites or ignores the changes other developers are publishing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tested and found that:

1. Multiple users can access the same Data factory and working with
   different pipelines in same time.
2. Publish only affect the current user and the current pipeline which
   user is developing and editing. It won't overwrites other pipelines.

For you question:

**Is it possible to work parallelly for a team of 3 or more developers, without corrupting the main JSON?**

Yes, it's possible.

**One of the developer publishes his/her updates, does it somehow overwrites or ignores the changes other developers are publishing?**

No, it doesn't. For example, user A only develop with pipeline A, then publish again. The Publish only affect the current pipeline, won't overwrite or affection other pipelines.

You could test and prove it.

**Update:**

Thanks @V_Singh for share us the Microsoft suggestion:

Microsoft suggested to use CI/CD only, otherwise there will be some disparity in code.

Reply from Microsoft:

"**In Live Mode can hit unexpected errors if you try to publish because you may have not the latest version ( For Example user A publish, user B is using old version and depends on an old resource and try to publish) not possible. Suggested to please use Git, since it is intended for collaborative scenarios.**"

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks Leon for looking into this.

Microsoft suggested to use CI/CD only, otherwise there will be some disparity in code.
Reply from Microsoft:
"In Live Mode can hit unexpected errors if you try to publish because you may have not the latest version ( For Example user A publish, user B is using old version and depends on an old resource and try to publish) not possible.

Suggested to please use Git, since it is intended for collaborative scenarios."

Comment: @V_Singh You're welcome and thanks for share me the Microsoft suggestions! Can I add this to the answer? Then you could think about mark it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you and have a good day!

Comment: Hi @V_Singh hope you're doing well. Haven't heard you for a long time, do you have other concerns?